# ST_DWithin with variable distance in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, buffer, st-dwithin

I have a table of two columns:

1. Polylines (Linestrings) geometry coordinates.
2. Buffers: distance in kilometers.

The table contains about 1000 entries.
Using PostGIS "ST_DWithin" or any relevant tool, I want to find the entries which are within a specific distance from the 10th entry (for example).
The problem is that the distance is not a constant number, I want to sum the buffers of the 10th entry and that of each entry individually and check each one separately, e.g.:

```
ST_DWithin(10th.geom, 1st.geom, (10th.Buffer + 1st.Buffer)) # ...

# or 

ST_DWithin(10th.geom, 2nd.geom, (10th.Buffer + 2nd.Buffer)) # ...and so on.
```

How to do this?

Comment: So long as the distance associated with the buffer is available, this is trivial in a simple join. Please [Edit] the Question to add your coding attempt, so we know the table names involved and the names of the distance columns, and describe the problem you've encountered.

Comment: The buffer column is what? Polygon geometries?